# Fastest way to check if the set contains numbers in a given range in Python

Tags: python, set, range

What is the fastest way to check if a set contains at least one number within a given range?

For example `setA = set(1,4,7,9,10)`, `lowerRange=6`, `upperRange=8`, will return True because of 7.

Currently I am using:

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: lowerRange<=x<=upperRange,setA)
```

Then if filtered is not empty, returns a True.

Assuming that setA can be a very large set, is this the optimal solution?  Or is this iterating through the entire setA?

Comment: Are they always ints?

Comment: Yes, always int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the membership chick is approximately O(1) for sets you can use a generator expression within `any()` built-in function:

```
rng = range(6, 9)
any(i in setA for i in rng)
```

Note that for a short range you'll give a better performance with `set.intersection()`:

```
In [2]: a = {1,4,7,9,10}

In [3]: rng = range(6, 9)

In [8]: %timeit bool(a.intersection(rng))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 344 ns per loop

In [9]: %timeit any(i in a for i in rng)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 620 ns per loop
```

But in this case for longer ranges you'd definitely go with `any()`:

```
In [10]: rng = range(6, 9000)

In [11]: %timeit any(i in a for i in rng)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 620 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit bool(a.intersection(rng))
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 µs per loop
```

And note that the reason that `any()` performs better is because it returns True right after it encounter an item that exist in your set (based on our membership condition) an since the number 8 is at the beginning of the range it makes the `any()` per forms so fast. Also as mentioned in comment as a more pythonic way for checking the validity of the intersection of an iterable within a set you can use `isdisjoint()` method. Here is a benchmark with this method for small rage:

```
In [26]: %timeit not a.isdisjoint(rng)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 153 ns per loop

In [27]: %timeit any(i in a for i in rng)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 609 ns per loop
```

And here is a benchmark that makes the `any()` checks the membership for all the numbers which shows that `isdisjoint()` performs so better:

```
In [29]: rng = range(8, 1000)

In [30]: %timeit any(i in a for i in rng)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 595 ns per loop

In [31]: %timeit not a.isdisjoint(rng)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 142 ns per loop
```

Comment: It should be `range(6, 9)`. The question specifies inclusiveness on both ends.

Comment: @SarcasticSully It's not in OP's explanations. But yeah it's in the code! just fixed.

Comment: `isdisjoint` beats `intersection` for this purpose, since it doesn't need to build a whole result set: `not a.isdisjoint(rng)`

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has an inherent bias in your test methodology: `any()` will return immediately once it finds a single example... in this case, it only processes 2 numbers(6, 7) before returning, which is why it is beating intersection. If the range was not so strongly biased in it's favor, `intersection` will probably be more competitive.

Comment: Of course, for large ranges or non-integer elements, either version will be terrible. Really, a `set` isn't a good data structure for this operation. A sorted list or some more sophisticated comparison-based data structure may be appropriate.

Comment: It's also reasonable to consider converting the range to a set and then doing a simple intersection/isdisjoint. If you will use the range more than once this will likely yield an improvement.

Comment: @user2357112 Indeed, `isdisjoint` is exactly the most appropriate method for this task.

Comment: If you use `isdisjoint`, remember that it returns True if the intersection is empty, not if the intersection contains something, so you may need to negate the result.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yes, in fact I was about the add a more comprehensive explanation about that point too. Thanks for note!

Comment: [repl.it](https://repl.it/GLTE/3) demonstration of the bias by showing the `rng` vs `rrng` (the same range, reversed). Unsurprisingly, `isdisjoint` also benefits from this.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Yeah that's all because of the number of loop in `any()`. I updated the answer by explaining the both situations.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to work with a sorted list or tuple instead of a set.  That way you can do the range searches using the [bisect module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan to use those values, using the `filter` function is unnecessary, because it stores data that you won't end up using. It also keeps going even after it finds one that fits the criteria, slowing you down quite a bit.

My solution would have been to write and use the following function.

```
def check(list, lower, upper):
    for i in list:
        if i >= lower and i <= upper:
            return True
    return False
```

Like with @Kasramvd's answer, and your idea, this is the brute-force search (O(n) solution). That's impossible to beat unless there are some constraints on the data beforehand, like that it has to be sorted.

Comment: More Pythonic: `lower <= i <= upper`.